# Creation and usage coordinates grid

Tags: python, numpy

Can anybody help me - is there any way to create coordinates grid as numpy array like this?

```
(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) ... (0,n)
(1,0) (1,1) (1,2) ... (1,n)
...........................
(m,0) (m,1) (m,2) ... (m,n)
```

If yes, how can I find distance from every point to circle with center in (m/2, n/2) and radius R?

```
(x - m/2)^2 + (y - n/2)^2 - R^2 = ?
```

Comment: You can check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17663393 for a similar example.

Comment: Good point, the two questions are very similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A standard way of doing this is with the `meshgrid` function. It makes two arrays, with the `x` and `y` coordinates of the points you want. To get the coordinates shown in your question you can do

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(m+1)
y = np.arange(n+1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
```

then to calculate the distance you want you can do

```
np.sqrt((X - m/2.)**2 + (Y - n/2.)**2) - R
```

For more information on `meshgrid` see the documentation
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html

Also, if you want evenly spaced values between two endpoints instead of just `0` through `m` or `0` through `n`, consider using the `linspace` function.

Comment: Since it looks like the OP is new to numpy, I want to add how to actually get the coordinates. If you let `idx = np.sqrt((X - m/2.)**2 + (Y - n/2.)**2 - R**2)`, `idx` is now a mask of True/False values the same size as `X`. Hence `X[idx]` and `Y[idx]` return only the coordinates in the circle.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me notice a typo in my solution, I just fixed it. I think what you mean to do is set `idx = ((X - m/2.)**2 + (Y - n/2.)**2) < R**2`